# Tick sound on every pedal only for 5 minutes

Tags: pedals, noise, front

I am having a new MTB Montra Rock 1.0D 2016.

When I ride my cycle, for first 5 to 10 minutes, I hear a tick sound on every pedal when my pedal is at 3'o clock to 6'o clock position on my right foot.

After few minutes, no noise at all and everything is quiet and smooth.

Next day, same happens for first few minutes.

I couldn't figure out source of the tick.

Also to note that, when cycle is standstill, no tick sound at all when moving pedal with hand, not for few minutes also, means no tick at all and thats what I want.

If i ride cycle, then only I hear tick for first few minutes

Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**

[BIKE SPECIFICATION](https://scontent.fbom1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14079834_835667683235503_8366036185128653369_n.jpg?oh=526b3ad43a1f0bf739d158d1be757b25&oe=5866E6E7)

Comment: Have you tried a different pair of pedals?

Comment: No, the original one only.

Comment: But how its possible that noise comes for few minutes initially only?

Comment: It might just be your brain filtering the noise out after a bit. In any case, trying a different set of pedals should be a quick test.

Comment: There are some other questions that duplicate this, but I can't find them just now.  Possible causes are bad pedals, pedals not screwed into the crank arms properly, crank arms not tightly fastened to crank shaft, chain rings not tightly fastened to crank spider, bad crank bearings, crank bearings loose in the BB.  Of these, having the crank arms not properly fastened to the shaft is all too common and rapidly leads to destruction of the arms and crank.  The others are less concerning (though annoying).

Comment: Possible dup: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13025/why-does-my-bike-make-a-noise-when-i-pedal-hard

Comment: Might be loose chain may be wobbling around and slightly touching front derailleur on each pedal stroke. Is there any way to widen front derailleur or tighten the chain easily? It might be possible that initially chain is loose and lengthen by 2 to 3 mms. When I start using it for few minutes chain gets tight due to pedal stroke and wobbling and front derailleur touching is gone. Am I correct?

Comment: @Hemal You're not correct. First, the top half of the chain (the part that runs through the derailleur) is under tension when pedaling, so it can't wobble around. Second, I can't see any mechanism that would cause the chain to get shorter after using it for a bit.

Comment: first and easiest step is to grease the pedal threads - this was the solution for me when i had similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue on my bike last year. Drove me crazy. Only happened when pedaling and rate of clicks depended on cadence, was not changed by gears. Turned out to be slightly dry/loose pedal threads, i.e. where the pedal spindle threads into the crank arm, not the inernal bearings of the pedal itself:

[image]

Try this: remove the pedals, clean the threads with an old rag, apply a small amount of grease to the threads. Put them back in and tighten up quite firmly. See if clicking disappears. I find I have to do that every 2-4,000 km or so.

Don't forget left pedal is threaded the opposite of "normal".

Comment: Will try this and let you know.

Comment: I tried removing right pedal and removed it from crank. Then I reattached it without any greasing and noise is gone. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. FYI: typically you should apply a small amount of grease to the threads before installing or reinstalling a pedal. This is so it is easy to remove at a later date. Note that the pedals are threaded such that when you are pedalling, the rotation applied to the threads is a tightening one, so you don't have to worry that the pedal is going to work itself loose if you grease it.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible cause:**

Without any further knowledge about your bike, I'd guess that the clicking noise has something to make with a **grease** in either the pedal or the crank bearings. *(As you mentioned that the sound occurs only when the pedals are in the very same position and when you actually put some force on them, I'd say it isn't caused by something like an unevenly tightend handle bar or loose seat post etc etc..)*

Since you only hear the clicks within the first 5 - 10 min when riding, I assume this is the time the grease needs to "warm up", as in become slightly more fluid due to the friction it experiences. During this time some of the little balls inside the bearings could cause the clicking noises.

**Possible solution:**

- Make sure that the pedal bearings arent tightend too much (in case
  you can open them at all).
- check on your cranks, whether they're tightend properly
- check on the more unlikely sources for the click (i.e. seat post, saddle, etc.)
- replace bottom bracket

I'd also advice you to do these steps iteratively, so you get to know the source of the problem.

Comment: Sure, will look into this and will let you know.

Comment: But if there is a problem with rear hub or bottom bracket, why the noise is not coming when cycle is standstill/on trainer/on stand?Noise appears when I am on the cycle riding.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not your pedals or bottom bracket, as covered by [dru87's answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/43241/13174), it's your rear hub: that was the cause of a similar noise on my own bike a couple of months ago. The reason it only happens at a particular point in your pedal stroke is that that's when you're pushing hardest; the reason it goes away after a few minutes is, as in dru's answer, that there's not enough lubricating grease but, after a little while it's warmed up enough to flow more and cover the whole bearing.

Comment: May I know how do I get rid off this?

Comment: I would expect some correlation between front derailleur gear and frequency of clicking in this case unless it's a single speed or 1x drivetrain which it is not.

Comment: @SSilk When I had a creak caused by a rear hub problem, it was once per rotation of the pedals.

Comment: But if there is a problem with rear hub or bottom bracket, why the noise is not coming when cycle is standstill/on trainer/on stand?Noise appears when I am on the cycle riding.

Comment: @Hemal Because the noise is caused by the strain of you pedalling. When you pedal, you exert a force that's a decent fraction of your weight, which is multiplied by the lever arm of the crank and chainring.

Comment: Oh, and I fixed the problem by taking the bike to a bike shop -- sorry I can't give more useful advice than that.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be your crank hitting the crimp cap for the front derailleur cable, check if your cable is sticking out a little bit.

Comment: Checked it, not a problem